# Python threads memory leak

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I have a class like this:

```
class Detector:
    ...
    def detect:
        sniff(iface='eth6', filter='vlan or not vlan and udp port 53', prn=self.spawnThread, store=0)

    def spawnThread(self, pkt):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.predict, args=(pkt,))
        t.start()

    def predict(self, pkt):
        # do something
        # write log file with logging module
```

where`sniff()` is a method from [scapy](https://scapy.net/), for every packet it captured, it passes the packet to `spawnThread`, in `spawnThread` I want to create different threads to run `predict` method.

But there seems to be a memory leak, I checked with Heapy and get this output:

```
    Partition of a set of 623561 objects. Total size = 87355208 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 236145  38 26871176  31  26871176  31 str
     1 139658  22 13805832  16  40677008  47 tuple
     2   6565   1  7366648   8  48043656  55 dict (no owner)
     3   1408   0  6592768   8  54636424  63 dict of module
     4  25764   4  3297792   4  57934216  66 types.CodeType
     5  17737   3  3223240   4  61157456  70 list
     6  24878   4  2985360   3  64142816  73 function
     7  14367   2  2577384   3  66720200  76 unicode
     8   2445   0  2206320   3  68926520  79 type
     9   2445   0  2173752   2  71100272  81 dict of type
```

the count and size of tuple objects keeps growing, I think that's what causes memory leak but I don't know where and why. Thanks for any feed back!

Update: If I directly call `predict` from `sniff` without using threads, there is no memory leak. And also, there are no other tuple objects anywhere else in the class. in `__init__` I just initiated some strings like paths and names.

```
class Detector:
    ...
    def detect(self):
        sniff(iface='eth6', filter='vlan or not vlan and udp port 53', 
            prn=self.predict, store=0)

    def predict(self, pkt):
        # do something with pkt
        # write log file with loggin module
```

Comment: There's not enough context here to tell where or whether you're keeping objects alive that you probably don't want to.

Comment: You're not keeping any class level reference to the threads you're creating. Those rogue threads might have something to do with it.

Comment: @jedwards there are no other tuple objects in the class, so I think maybe the parameter `(pkt,)` passed by `spawnThread` is not properly destroyed after the thread is done running `predict`.